# Split string that looks like a Python function call to arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that accepts string that looks like function call in python and returns the arguments to the function
Example:

```
"fun(1, bar(x+17, 1), arr = 's,y')"
```

will result:

```
["1", "bar(x+17, 1)", "arr = 's,y'"]
```

The problem of using regular expressions is that I don't know if it is possible to not split at the commas inside parenthesis or quotes.
Thanks.

Edit: this [Python: splitting a function and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645061/python-splitting-a-function-and-arguments) doesn't answer correctly the quastions since it doesn't treat commas in parenthesis or quotes.

As @Kevin said, **regular expressions cannot solve this** since they can't handle nested parenthesis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex question about parsing method signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493844/regex-question-about-parsing-method-signature)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

Comment: You should use a regular expression to parse the stuff in between parentheses, and then split that that string to find your arguments

Comment: All these do not treat correctly commas in parenthesis or quotes. like in the example

Comment: "vanilla" regexes can't parse nested parentheses. Maybe you can do it with more advanced features, but at some point it's going to be complex enough that you may as well just write a parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial evaluation with pyparsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920588/partial-evaluation-with-pyparsing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can keep track of your own state fairly simply with something like

```
def parse_arguments(s):
    openers = "{[\"'("
    closers = "}]\"')"
    state = []
    current = ""
    for c in s:
        if c == "," and not state:
           yield current
           current = ""
        else:
           current += c
           if c in openers:
              state.append(c)
           elif c in closers:
              assert state, "ERROR No Opener for %s"%c
              assert state[-1] == openers[closers.index(c)],"ERROR Mismatched %s %s"%(state[-1],c)
              state.pop(-1)
    assert not state, "ERROR Unexpected End, expected %s"%state[-1]
    yield current

print list(parse_arguments("1, bar(x+17, 1), arr = 's,y'"))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `parse_arguments("hello")`, I think because `"` is both closing and opening? I think it also will try to match openers/closers within strings, which it shouldn't.

Comment: I tried my best at an enhancement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633243/2124834

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to this complex split function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "fun(1, bar(x+17, 1), arr = 's,y')"
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'''^\w+\(|\)$|((?:\([^()]*\)|'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"(),])*)''', s) if i and i !=',']
['1', 'bar(x+17, 1)', "arr = 's,y'"]
```

Comment: good answer ... but im pretty sure for any regex there exists some counter example that will break it .. (with nested parenthesis) +1 all the same as I cant think up a good counter example offhand (and even if i could) ... but debugging it when it doesnt work might be a little painful

Comment: that said I think there is an actual regexp module in pipi `import regex` that does support stack memory(and other advanced regex features)and so you could come up with a perfect regex solution using that module

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to do the with the `ast` (abstract syntax tree) standard library module, although it might be overkill:

```
>>> import ast
>>> parsed = ast.parse("fun(1, bar(x+17, 1), arr='s, y')")
>>> ast.dump(p.body[0].value)
"Call(func=Name(id='fun', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=1), 
Call(func=Name(id='bar', ctx=Load()), args=[BinOp(left=Name(id='x', 
ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Num(n=17)), Num(n=1)], keywords=[], 
starargs=None, kwargs=None)], keywords=[keyword(arg='arr', 
value=Str(s='s, y'))], starargs=None, kwargs=None)"
```

Unfortunately there's no standard library way to get those back to standard strings like `"1"`, `"bar(x+17, 1)"` and `"arr='s, y'"`. But https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astor can probably do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x="fun(1, bar(x+17, 1), arr = 's,y')"
print re.split(r",\s*(?![^\(]*\))(?![^']*'(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)",re.findall(r"^.*?\((.*)\)",x)[0])
```

You can try using `re`.

Output:`['1', 'bar(x+17, 1)', "arr = 's,y'"]`

Comment: as all regex answers, they fail on nested parenthesis. try x = "fun(bar(1,foo(1)))"

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Joran Beasley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547237/2124834) with hopefully better string handling? The only change is the new if-arm, allowing any characters when we're in a string, including an escaped quote.

```py
def parse_arguments(s):
    openers = "{[\"'("
    closers = "}]\"')"
    state = []
    current = ""
    for c in s:
        if c == "," and not state:
            yield current
            current = ""
        else:
            current += c
            if state and state[-1] in "\"'":
                if c == state[-1] and current[-1] != "\\":
                    state.pop(-1)
            else:
                if c in openers:
                    state.append(c)
                elif c in closers:
                    assert state, "ERROR No Opener for %s" % c
                    assert (
                        state[-1] == openers[closers.index(c)]
                    ), "ERROR Mismatched %s %s" % (state[-1], c)
                    state.pop(-1)
    assert not state, "ERROR Unexpected End, expected %s" % state[-1]
    yield current
```